# How do i find the row echelon form (REF)

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, linear-algebra

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

Vec = np.matrix([[1,1,1,5],[1,2,0,3],[2,1,3,12]]) 
Vec_rref = sp.Matrix(Vec).rref()
print(Vec_rref) ##<--  this code prints the RREF, but i am looking for the code for REF (See below)
```

I have found plenty of codes which solves the RREF but not codes for REF, if **it makes sense. The code i have developed gives the following:

```
(Matrix([
[1, 0,  2,  7],
[0, 1, -1, -2],
[0, 0,  0,  0]]), (0, 1))
```

I am looking for a code which should solve the following:

```
      1XXX
REF = 01XX
      001X
```

and not

```
       100X
RREF = 010X
       001X
```

New here so bare with me guys. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: can you allow row permutations?

Comment: Everything is allowed i'm just looking for a code to solve REF :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the function of sympy: rref which is associated to "reduced row-echelon form". You might want to use `.echelon_form()` instead

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

Vec = np.matrix([[1,1,1,5],
                 [1,2,0,3],
                 [2,1,3,12]]) 

Vec_rref = sp.Matrix(Vec).echelon_form()

print(Vec_rref)
```

Which outputs:

`Matrix([[1, 1, 1, 5], [0, 1, -1, -2], [0, 0, 0, 0]])`

Comment: Thank you very much Ulises! :-)